# Can't remove all "li" items from a list

Tags: jquery-mobile

Why doesn't this snippet remove all the data list `<li>` items?

```
jQuery("#list2 > li").each(function(n,item){         
   jQuery(item).remove();
});
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question:  1- what is it doing as-is?  2- what platforms are you intending this go to on?  I see that you tagged it as jquery-mobile but nothing in the code looks specific to mobile.  Did you mean to just tag it `jquery`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to loop, just do:

```
jQuery("#list2 > li").remove();
```

to remove all.